# Difference between %s and %1024s

Tags: c, string-formatting

I read that using "%1024s" instead of "%s" prevents a security hole being created in the code.
How is "%1024s" different from "%s"?

Comment: helps preventing this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Comment: There's a hidden security hole right there between `%` and `s`. You need exactly four bytes to plug it.

Answer (score 4):

In `scanf()`, presumably, right?

[So you can and you **should** read its man page.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)

Basically, `%1024s` maximizes the length of the string to be scanned in 1024 characters, so it will always fit in an 1025 byte long buffer (1024 + 1 for the 0-terminator). `%s` doesn't have this limitation, so if the buffer is smaller than the string `scanf()` tries to put inside, then a buffer overrun occurs, and the program will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Updated the link to the 2013 version of POSIX. It's been released, but their site is so poorly organized that it's hard to find.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks. What I linked was just the first Google hit (I tend to read those).

Comment: Note that using `"%1024s"` needs an array with space for 1025 characters. The terminating `'\0'` is not counted within the 1024 but is written to the aray all the same.

Comment: @pmg Right, I've updated that (I've written "the length of the string" correctly, yet failed to calculate the NUL terminator in...)